# CQRS/EventStore - changing two aggregates

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I have a command that updates two aggregates. Since aggregate routes are transactional boundaries, I have a command that does a repository.Save() action on the first aggregate and then I fire another command (from within the first command) which acts on the second aggregate. Each Save() actions starts its Event-Store transaction and commits the changes and then publishes them.

First is this correct, i.e. letting one command notify another aggregate via another command?

I noticed in Mark Nihjof's code that he uses event handlers which is nice as you could register the event handlers to the same event. I tried doing this using J Oliver's Event-Store but my commits.events in IDispatchCommit were referencing the first aggregates values when processing the second. This caused some weird errors.

So should I find a way of making this work with EventHandlers or is firing off commands within commands okay?

JD

**Edit** - I have used switched my wire up to use .UsingAsynchronousDispatchScheduler() and am now allowing registered events to fire more than one event handler which in turn fires a command on the other aggregate and it seems to work. So, is this the correct way to do it and not use commmands firing commands?

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a million and one ways to skin this cat. I'm not sure firing a command from an event handler is the way to go, I have to command handlers respond to the same command in this instance.

I do find [documently](https://github.com/haf/Documently) good for a reference app. Have you looked a that?

Comment: Thanks. Will have a read over the weekend. So, how do I I change a second aggregate if I cannot fire another command from the first aggregate roots event handler?